# How to get google maps api key

Tags: android, google-maps

How to get google maps api key for android, i have read more one articles but not success.

i look code android as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

So my question how to get xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx from google?
Please give me step by step, thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: you can find it easily by googling.

Comment: Yup, i have get apikey, but now error Couldn't get connection factory client, just blank in mapview, do you know this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Before you start, you will need a specific API key from Google. The key is free, and are required to complete this process.

Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/, and log in with your Google Account.

The following will appear:

Click on the "Create Project" button.

In the list of services, find Google Maps API v3, and click on "off" to turn it on.

In the next screen, check "I Agree..." and the click the "Accept" button. You will now see that the button next to Google Maps API v3 has changed to "on".

Then click "API Access" in the menu to the left. It will ask you to "Create an OAuth 2.0 client id...".

In the next screen, provide a product name (e.g. "demo"), upload an image (if you want to) as a logo of your project, and click the "Next" button.

In the next screen, choose Application type ("Web application"), and type in your web address, and then click the "Create Client Id" button.

In the next screen, you have got an API key.

Remark Note: Save your API key! (You will need it for all Google Maps applications you develop for the particular URL

Comment: Good answare @Sagar

Answer (score 3):

1. In command line  you need to open Java-> jdk-> bin 
   as for me  it  is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"
2. There is "keytool" program which u need. In command line enter "cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"
3. And enter "keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\John\.android\debug.keystore"
   So the final string in command line must look like:
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\John\.android\debug.keystore". Whare usually u need only to change the name "John"

There will be SHA-1, MD5, etc

Finally, go to Google Access API [google access api](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:32596228624%3aaccess)

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

Google is not your friend?

```
$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: Yup, i have get apikey, but now error Couldn't get connection factory client, just blank in mapview, do you know this problem?

Comment: You need a Kay for debug certificate (see link) and one for final release. I guess you used the wrong one.

Comment: I just solved, from this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html
thanks.

Comment: Yah, as your question was specific, I replied with the same answer than what is written in chapter 4.2 of the link you sent. This is actually the answer to "how to get an api key" with a more detailled link. Can you consider accepting or voting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Google has updated its Google maps api for android you should check this out [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro)

Comment: Yup, i have get apikey, but now error Couldn't get connection factory client, just blank in mapview, do you know this problem?

Comment: it means you cannot connect to google play services have you add the google play library and added all the permission in your manifest

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggest, i want to googling again, thanks man,